# SP 2013 Nested IF statement calculated column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to make a nested IF statement where: less than or equal to 45 is green; greater than 45 and less than or equal to 90 is gold; and greater than 90 is red

The individual code works fine by itself, but I can't seem to nest them.

(less than or equal to 45 is green)

```
="<span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:48px; color:"&IF(Count<=45,"green"&";'>●</span>")
```

(greater than 45 and less than or equal to 90 is gold)

```
="<span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:48px; color:"&IF(Count>45,"gold"&";'>●</span>")
```

(greater than 90 is red)

```
="<span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:48px; color:"&IF(Count>90,"red"&";'>●</span>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="StartOffWithAnyTextYouNeedLikeOpeningSingleQuotes" &
IF([FIElD]<=45,"green",IF(AND([FIELD]>45,[FIELD]<=90),"gold","red")) &
";'>dot AndFinishOffAnythingElse"
```

Start it off with whatever you are building, then add in the green/gold/red, then finish off with our closing quotes.

Comment: Thank you, Robin!  YOU ROCK!  That worked.  The AND statement stumped me.  Thanks again!